# How to make AspectJ work on the server

Tags: java, maven, web, aop, aspectj

I am using AspectJ (not Spring) to implement AOP in my Java Web application. It works fine when built by Maven project in Eclipse.

But putting and deploying the war package on the remote server, the AOP won't execute.

here's part of `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    <!--<properties>
            <war.bundle>true</war.bundle>
        </properties>
          -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    <!--<properties>
            <war.bundle>true</war.bundle>
        </properties>
          -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <!--<properties>
            <war.bundle>true</war.bundle>
        </properties>
          -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <privateScope>true</privateScope>
               <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
               <source>1.7</source>
               <target>1.7</target>
               <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
               <!-- <encoding>UTF-8</encoding> -->
               <verbose>false</verbose>
               <outxml>true</outxml>
               <aspectLibraries>
                </aspectLibraries>
             </configuration>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/../deploy</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${project.artifactId}.war</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-installed</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                <destFileName>rm-cloud-web.war</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../deploy</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any advice?

Sorry guys, AspectJ did work on the server side and it does NOT need to add any extra jar file. I tried to log some info in an aspect method by using a enum that been advised, means the advise will be called recursively that caused stackoverflowexception.

Now I cant exclude Enum whthin the curtain class:

LogLevel is a enum in the class: xxx.xx.Utility

The compile info:

[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(int[] xxx.xx.Utility.$SWITCH_TABLE$xxx$xx$Utility$LogLevel())' in Type 'xxx.xx.Utility' (Utility.java:49) advised by before advice from 'zzz.zz.AAAA' (AAAA.aj:5)

my aspect content:

pointcut pc() : (execution(* xxx.xx.*.*(..)) && !within(is(EnumType)));
before() : pc() {
    ...
}

Comment: Any code to show us? Anything in the logs?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with the previous commentators. We need more information. Besides, I am wondering why you use current versions 1.8.9 of AspectJ runtime and tools, but a completely outdated version 1.6.8 of AspectJ weaver which only supports Java 6, not 7/8. In a load-time weaving situation probably you do not want that. As for AspectJ Maven plugin, you could also bump the version to 1.9. Maybe all of this does not solve your problem, but some build hygiene is in order, I guess.

Comment: have you find a solution for that please? i have the same problem.